# php explode delimiter with numbers?

Tags: php, explode, paragraph

So I'm trying to explode a string that has a list of answers.

ex: ANSWERS: 1. Comb. 2. Thumb. 3. Tomb (catacomb). 4. Womb. 5. Crumb. 6. Bomb. 7. Numb. 8. Aplomb. 9. Succumb.

Is there a way to explode this to come out like the following:

```
$answer = explode("something here", $answerString);
$answer[1] = 1. Comb.
$answer[2] = 2. Thumb.
$answer[3] = 3. 3. Tomb (catacomb).
```

The tricky thing is that I want to explode this string so that each answer can be separated after a number.

So, if the answer is 1 character, or 10 words, it will still split after each number.

Thanks.

Comment: There's no perfect way to do it if an answer itself contains something like `"Test 5. 6. 7. "`. I think you'd be better off getting the source input into a better format.

Comment: Do you mean `$answer[2] = "3. Tomb (catacomb)."`? (Note you have your array indices starting at 1 instead of 0, and you have two `3.`s in your example)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is not possible with explode(), but you can use **[`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)**

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/4b041/1

```
<?php 
$str = '1. Comb. 2. Thumb. 3. Tomb (catacomb). 4. Womb. 5. Crumb. 6. Bomb. 7. Numb. 8. Aplomb. 9. Succumb'; 
$exploded = preg_split('/[0-9]+\./', $str); 
foreach($exploded as $index => $answer){ 
    if (!empty($answer)){ 
        echo $index.": ".$answer."<br />"; 
    } 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to use [`preg_split()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) instead. Something like:

```
$answer = preg_split('/\d\./', $answerString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$org_string = "1. Comb. 2. Thumb. 3. Tomb (catacomb). 4. Womb. 5. Crumb. 6. Bomb. 7. Numb. 8. Aplomb. 9. Succumb";
$new_string = str_replace("b. ", "b. ,", $org_string);
$final_string = str_replace("b). ", "b). ,", $new_string);
$exploded = explode(" ,",$final_string);
foreach($exploded as $answer){ 

        echo $answer."<br />"; 
    } 
?>
```